# Pythonic way to convert numpy.ndarray to list in dataframe in situ

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe df_combined_test and I would like to convert the values in one of the columns [title_w2v] from numpy.ndarray to list. Is there an easy pythonic way to do this?

I have tried the following with not much luck

```
df_combined_test['title_w2v'] = pd.DataFrame(df_combined_test.title_w2v=arr.flatten())
```

I also tried the following

```
df_combined_test['title_w2v'] = df_combined_test['title_w2v'].apply(lambda x: x.to_list())
```

Comment: Is each element a 1-dimensional np.ndarray or is it multi-dimensional?

Comment: multi dimensional

Comment: I created a function which works when i apply to the column but was wondering if theres an easier way
. def convert_list(x):
  x1 = x.tolist()
  return x1

Comment: Can you show how you apply `convert_list(x)`?

Comment: I am trying to build an example to test, and I can get a column from a ndarray, but if I try to assign a multidimensional to an element pandas complains, so I don't know what kind of data structure you are working with.

Comment: df_combined['title_w2v'] = df_combined['title_w2v'].apply(lambda x: convert_list(x))

Comment: the content is a range of numbers float saved in numpy array

Comment: It's isn't pandonic to have numpy.ndarray objects, or list objects, as items in your dataframe

Comment: Did the answer below work?

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of the original dataframe it is hard to test a solution. That said, one thing I noticed is that I believe

```
covert_list(x): 
   x1 = x.tolist()
   return x1
```

is exactly the same as `x.tolist()`. Also, `apply()` takes a function as an argument, so `apply(lambda x: convert_list(x)))` should be exactly the same as `apply(to_list)` (note there are *no parenthesis* on functions passed into `apply()`). So in theory this should work:

```
df_combined_test['title_w2v'] = df_combined_test['title_w2v'].apply(to_list)
```